# What's the difference between Meteor and Meteorite (mrt)?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

For example, some sites tell me to use `mrt add accounts-ui` (using Meteorite, right?) and others say `meteor add accounts-ui`.

From what I understand, [Meteorite](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite) is just a version control / package manager. Is this correct? What is the difference between the two commands above?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Update**

Meteor 0.9 release rendered Meteorite and the `mrt` command obsolete. All new projects should use `meteor add` only.

**Original answer**

`meteor add` works only for packages issues officially by the Meteor team ([here's the list](http://docs.meteor.com/#packages)). `mrt add` is a wrapper that works also for all community packages available from [atmosphere](http://atmosphere.meteor.com/).

Comment: One question: is there a difference in starting a meteor app by typing "mrt" or "meteor"?

Comment: `mrt` fetch all necessary packages from atmosphere if you don't have them locally, while `meteor` works only with local copies of packages. So if your app uses a package that hasn't been prefetched, `mrt` will run while `meteor` will crash. It's generally better to use `meteor`, as this is closer to what the app will look like in production.

Comment: As [Pahlevi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/701589/pahlevi-fikri-auliya) mentioned, meteorite is no longer needed as of 0.9.0. Just use `meteor add author:package`. You can look up package authors and names here: https://atmospherejs.com/

Comment: So this is 2018 and I am still seeing 'mrt add' for new and recent packages

Answer (score 10):

They are the same now
https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/

"NOTE: As of Meteor 0.9.0, Meteorite is no longer required! You can now install Atmosphere packages directly via the meteor tool."

Answer (score 2):

You're right, Meteorite is a packaging system for [Meteor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteor_%28platform%29). The repository of Meteorite is [Atmosphere](https://github.com/oortcloud/atmosphere). It's like a "composer" system with a packagist repository for the PHP language.

So, when you do a "meteor add", you only use the package delivered with the Meteor installation. But with "mrt add", you will be bound to the Meteor original package, like `meteor add`, or to an Atmosphere repository for all other packages.
Finally, because everybody use Meteorite, you just have to use the "mrt" command.