# How can I delete a meteorite (atmosphere) package?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

I want to delete a atmosphere package from my app, but I don't know how to remove it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is so easy. In your directory in terminal write it;

```
mrt remove package_name
```

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes meteorite can be a bit glitchy depending on the version you have. Usually `mrt remove package_name` should do it but doing all of these should remove it and not let it get back till you add it back.

1. Run

   `mrt remove package_name`
2. Check your `smart.json` to see if your package has been removed from the `packages : {}` section.
3. Delete the package/symlink if it still exists in `/packages`.
4. If you still get an error claiming the package is not found remove it from meteor too

   `meteor remove package_name`

Comment: Yup, I've found that meteorite can be a bit 'clingy' on packages it's downloaded.

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer. I tried mrt remove <package> and while it said it removed it, the package was still in my smart.json, a file I didn't even know existed before reading your answer.

Comment: @JamesNisbet Keep in mind mrt has been deprecated now. We don't use smart.json/meteorite anymore. Meteor 0.9.x merged meteorite in, so you can just use `meteor add xxx` and `meteor remove xxx` on its own now. You *CAN* still use meteorite for private packages though. I wouldn't recommend it for the stuff on atmosphere though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `meteor remove package_name`

For example: `meteor remove kadira:flow-router`

> Meteor 0.9 release rendered Meteorite and the mrt command obsolete.
>   All new projects should use meteor >> [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227920/whats-the-difference-between-meteor-and-meteorite-mrt)